# How to access variable define in linker script in c?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

In the linker script, I defined `PROVIDE(__KERNEL_BEGIN__ = .);`.

The address can be accessed from:

```
extern uint32_t __KERNEL_BEGIN__[];
```

But, the following does not work (gives an incorrect address):

```
extern uint32_t * __KERNEL_BEGIN__;
```

I looked at the assembly. The first method, `__KERNEL_BEGIN__`, provides the exact address. The second one, `__KERNEL_BEGIN__ = [address]`, looks up a value at the address.

So, must it be this way? I cannot tell the difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to take the address of the `extern` variable. It is not completely intuitive but is explained in [the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Source-Code-Reference.html).

In theory, the `extern` can be any primitive data type. For reasons which I am unaware, the convention is to use a `char`:

```
extern char __KERNEL_BEGIN__;
```

Then to get the address exported from the linker script, take the address of `__KERNEL_BEGIN__`:

```
printf("Address: %08x\n", &__KERNEL_BEGIN__);
```

You can read about this in [the manual for `ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Source-Code-Reference.html).

Comment: I am little bit confused about using the & operator rather than * operator. Knowing that linker script variables are just symbols whose values represent memory addresses, then I expect that *foo = 5 means: write 5 to the memory location foo. I don't get the sense of &foo = 5. Any help ?

Comment: @AhmedAdel "Linker scripts symbol declarations, by contrast, create an entry in the symbol table but do not assign any memory to them. Thus they are an address without a value." in [the manual for ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Source-Code-Reference.html)

Answer (score 6):

This is more in reference to your follow-up question beneath Ryan's post, however it may help answer your original question as well.

"Variables" defined in linker scripts aren't treated the same as those defined in C; they're more *symbols* than anything. When accessing these *symbols* defined in your linker scripts, you **must** use the & operator.

For example, if we had the following section in our linker script:

```
.data :
{
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data*);
    _edata = .;
} > ram AT >rom
```

We could get a pointer to the start of the `.data` section like so:

```
uint8_t *data_ptr = &_sdata;
```

For further reading, try [the binutils docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Source-Code-Reference.html), or [this excellent primer on linker scripts](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/how-to-write-linker-scripts-for-firmware)

Cheers