# Linker script variable in library prevents dynamic linking

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a project set up where I compile and link a shared library (**libexample.so**) with a linker script that looks like this:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .modules : {
        __MODULES_START = .;
        KEEP(*(.mod*));
        __MODULES_END = .;
    }
    ...
}
```

I use these in my code to load modules compiled into the library.

```c
extern uint32_t __MODULES_START;
extern uint32_t __MODULES_END;

unsigned int init_mods (void) {
    void (*p)(void) = (void *)&__MODULES_START;
    ...
}
```

And when I compile the library in my Makefile

```
build/%.o: %.c
  gcc -o $@ -c $< -fPIC -g -Os -Iinclude

bin/libexample.so: $(OBJS)
  gcc -o $@ $^ -shared -fPIC -lc -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
```

It builds and links just fine, and it works when I try to link the library to another project that calls "init_mods".

```
build/%.o: %.c
  gcc -o $@ -c $< -fPIE -g -Os -Iinclude -I../libexample/include

bin/untitled-program: $(OBJS)
  gcc -o $@ $^ -fPIE -lc -lexample -Lbin '-Wl,-rpath,$$ORIGIN'
```

However, when I run the program where it can find the library, I receive the following linking error:

```
/bin/untitled-program: error while loading shared libraries: /blah/blah/libexample.so: unexpected PLT reloc type 0x08
```

When I readelf the shared library, I get the two definitions in my symbol table

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 223 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
...
   154: 0000000000000050     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 __MODULE_INIT_END
...
   222: 0000000000000028     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 __MODULE_INIT_START
```

So I'm wondering if my issue has to do with the NOTYPE, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on this.

To explain why I think my issue has to do with the linker script variables, when I run my program with linker debugging on, one of them is the last one to show up.

```sh
$ LD_DEBUG=all ./untitled-program
...
     23856: symbol=__MODULE_END;  lookup in file=./bin/untitled-program [0]
     23856: symbol=__MODULE_END;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/libc.so.6 [0]
     23856: symbol=__MODULE_END;  lookup in file=./bin/libexample.so [0]
     23856: binding file ./bin/libexample.so [0] to ./bin/libexample.so [0]: normal symbol `__MODULE_END'
...
     23856: symbol=__MODULE_START;  lookup in file=./bin/untitled-program [0]
     23856: symbol=__MODULE_START;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/libc.so.6 [0]
     23856: symbol=__MODULE_START;  lookup in file=./bin/libexample.so [0]
     23856: binding file ./bin/libexample.so [0] to ./bin/libexample.so [0]: normal symbol `__MODULE_START'
./bin/untitled-program: error while loading shared libraries: ./bin/libexample.so: unexpected PLT reloc type 0x08
```

But, that's the weird thing because it's able to bind one of the other linker script variables before it fails.

I have been working on this issue for too long, so I'm having trouble seeing the bigger picture.  Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong and the issue is with another symbol.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: It's likely that the problem is caused by a symbol reference in `libretroengine.so`, but you are not describing what you are doing there.

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that.  That's the actual name of the library I'm building, but I didn't want to create any unnecessary distractions in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mark your module init function with the GCC constructor function attribute (it has nothing to do with C++ constructors!), and it will include its address in the `init_array` section; the dynamic linker will then execute it before `main()`, or immediately when a dynamic library is loaded.

```
static void my_mod_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void my_mod_init(void)
{
    /* Initialize this module, hook up to the library */
}
```

This has the benefit that because the dynamic linker executes these automatically, these are also run when you load a dynamic library with such modules with e.g. `dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)`.

---

If you want to replicate the functionality under your own control,
then have each module declare an array of the init function addresses to a special section, say "mod_inits".  Define some helper macros:

```
#define  MERGE2_(a, b)  a ## b
#define  MERGE2(a, b)   MERGE2_(a, b)
#define  MODULE_INIT(func)  \
    static void *MERGE2(_init_, __LINE__) \
    __attribute__((section ("mod_inits"), used)) = &func
```

Then, in your module source files, make some functions:

```
static void hello(void) {
    puts("Hello!");
}
MODULE_INIT(hello);

static void also(void) {
    puts("Also hello!");
}
MODULE_INIT(also);
```

In the library file, to scan and execute all functions in any compilation units marked with `MODULE_INIT()`:

```
extern void *__start_mod_inits;
extern void *__stop_mod_inits;

void run_mod_inits(void)
{
    for (void **ptr = &__start_mod_inits; ptr < &__stop_mod_inits; ptr++) {
        void (*func)(void) = *ptr;

        func();  /* Could pass parameters, if they have the same prototype */

    }
}
```

You do not need any linker file for this, as gcc provides the `__start_` and `__stop_` symbols for all sections whose names are valid C identifiers.

Comment: This is a really awesome and well thought out answer!  I had looked into using constructors before, but as you said I wanted a little more control, so I tried using the provided __start_ and __stop_ symbols in your second answer (which I had no idea existed), and the program runs perfectly now!  Do you happen to know where the "unexpected PLT reloc type 0x08" issue comes from though?  It would be nice to find out why my linker script caused this to fail, and I'd expect others may have had the same problem.

Comment: @NicholasHein: The only thing that comes to mind is having the symbols be explicitly 32-bit (uint32_t) in the C code.  Does the error go away when you define them as void pointers or as size_t?

Comment: Hmm.  I think the external symbol can be any type [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086338/3663147).  I wish linker scripts had more documentation on this, but this solution solved my problem, so I'll mark it as accepted.  Thanks again!

Comment: @NicholasHein: But your linker script assigns the address of the symbol to the symbol itself; that's why I suspected it.. only testing if changing the type fixes it, would tell (and I'm too lazy).  Anyway, [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/)'s the documentation; it does include quite a few examples.