# Is there a way to find the address of a const variable in the map file?

Tags: c, linker, arm, embedded

I am writing embedded C-code with the Segger embedded Studio for a Nordic NRF52840 Microcontroller.
After compiling my code, I get a .map-file and a .hex file by the gcc.

I want to write a script, which is looking for the address of a constant variable in the .map file.
Then, the script should search for this address in the .hex-file and return the value of the constant variable, by reading the value from the .hex-file at this address.

My assumption is, that a constant variable should be placed in the Flash of the Microcontroller. Therefore, it should be present in the .hex-file. To find the address of this variable, I look for the Name of the variable in the .map file.

But now, I have the following behaviour of my compiler/linker:

In My code, I have defined the following variable in the main file and guaranteed, that the linker is not optimizing my constant:

```
uint32_t const test123= 0x12345;
int main()
{

  int retVal = foo_in_other_file();
  if(test123 == retval)
  {
    static volatile int i = 0;
    i++;
    retval = true;
  }

}
```

The Section around the constant in the .map-file looks like:

```
 .bss.is_asleeparr
                0x0000000000000000      0x400 temp/release/main.o
 .rodata.test123
                0x0000000000000000        0x4 temp/release/main.o
 .text          0x0000000000000000        0x0 temp/release/ble_advdata.o
 .data          0x0000000000000000        0x0 temp/release/ble_advdata.o
 .bss           0x0000000000000000        0x0 temp/release/ble_advdata.o
 .text.sd_ble_gap_addr_get
```

The constant variable *test123* is present in the .map file, but why is it's address zero?
Was it optimized away by the linker?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot of the disassembly. Does This mean, that the compiler does interprent the value as an immediate and it is not even stored into the flash?
If this is true, how van I avoid This?

[Disassembly of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPxPk.png)

Comment: Can you show the disassembly? The compiler might have optimized the variable as an immediate into an instruction, such that it doesn't explicitly appear in memory. Also, you can use the `nm` tool to more easily find the addresses of symbols. You could try attaching `__attribute__((used))` to the variable. You could also use the linker script to _always_ put the variable into the same address, to avoid looking it up each time.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sry, The "Flash"-Tag was incorrect

Comment: @Erlkoenig
I have added an image of my disassembly of the code.
Thanks for your advice, unfortunately the attribute"used"  does not change anything.
The Idea with the linker script is good, but I do not want to have a fix address of this variable. This would cause other problems in my software architecture

Comment: According to your screenshot (why not text?), the value should be located at address `0x2E6D2` (= `0xD*4+4+0x2E69A`). Try the `nm` tool instead of the map file. I suspect that the compiler changed the variable into a literal-pool-pseudo-immediate, i.e. a value in program memory (instead of `.rodata`). That might explain why it doesn't appear as a real variable with proper address anymore. Maybe `__attribute__((used, section(".rodata")))` helps.

Comment: @Erlkoenig sry for the screenshot. I did not know, that screenshots are not common here. I thought, the screenshot does show the connection between my c code and assembler.

Comment: Screenshots are usually frowned upon, because you can't copy&paste the code! If you show a screenshot to demonstrate some connection, show the code as text too.

Comment: okay, next time i will show the code as text :)
i have not done anything with the nm tool before. This is a linux tool right?
Unfortunately, I am developing on windows with the segger studio for windows.
Placing the variable to the rodata section did not change anything in the assembler.
The inly change is, that the variable has disappeared completely from the map file-

Comment: `nm` is part of binutils, which also contains the linker (`ld`). Binutils should already be installed as part of your compiler, possibly called `arm-none-eabi-nm.exe`. Just run it as `arm-none-eabi-nm.exe program.elf` and you will get the address of each symbol.

Comment: @Erlkoenig okay, thats great. I have started nm now. Unfortunately, the constant is not in the symbol list.
It seems, that there are only functions in the list of symbols and no variables.

Comment: Try reading the variables as `*((volatile uint32_t*) &test123)`. This should prevent the compiler from inlining the constant; then you won't need the attributes. Both linker map file and `nm` output should contain the proper address then.

Comment: The disassembly looks like, it uses a "load immediate" on every occurence where it is used `ldr  r2, =0x0012345`.  You could also try `static const uintt32_t test123 = 0x012345u;`. There might be certain optimizations enabled, so try also compiling with `-O1` to find out. Otherwise, you might try explicit section placememt.

Comment: From all of the comments, a better way to do this is to defne the constant in the linker file. You can explicitly position it there.  Do this with BYTE,SHORT,LONG, etc and [PROVIDES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998485/how-to-access-variable-define-in-linker-script-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help in the comments of my post, I could solve the problem.

With the following declaration, the address of the variable is shown in my map file:

`static uint32_t const test123 __attribute__((used)) = 0x4711;`

I had to access the variable as follows, to prevent the compiler and linker from optimization or use the variable as an immediate:

```
if(*((volatile uint32_t*) &test123) == 4711)
{
    static volatile uint32_t optimization_prevention = 0;
    optimization_prevention+= test123;
}
```

With this Code, the address of "test123" is shown in the .map file:

```
 .rodata.test123
                0x0000000000052dcc        0x4 temp/release/test_file.o
```

Thanks to all for the great help :)